# SharePoint 2013 - Find count of email send

Tags: 2013, outgoing-email

To foreseen some metrics, I want to see count of emails which has been sended to users in a day/ month / year by SharePoint.

Do you have any suggestion for this ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simply counting these emails on SharePoint, try to figure out, how to analyze these information on the Mail server, like Exchange, if there is auditing on, there should be possible to monitor incoming emails from SharePoint email address.